# knex multiple operations, one one after another, inside a transaction

Tags: knex.js

I need to run multiple operations against the database and I need to fit them all into a transaction. 
Here is how I do things and from my testing it does not seem to be right.

Basically for each operation I have a function that returns the knex promise. Based on the parameter, there may be no need to actually do anything, for instance, if there are not any rows to insert, I don't need to do anything

```
function insertRows(rowsToInsert, trx){
  if (rowsToInsert && rowsToInsert.length>0){
     return knex.batchInsert(...).transacting(trx) 
  }else{
    //no need to run
    return Promise.resolve() //this is probably wrong
  }
}
```

//I am returning a promise as I `yield` this function in a `co`

```
function process(params){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){

    knex.transaction(function(trx){
       return insertRows(rows, trx)
      .then(function (result){
          return insertRows(rows2,trx)
       }).then(function (result){
          return updateRows(rows3,trx)
       })
    }
  }
}
```

Running in this way I have noticed that sometimes I can get a deadlock between one update and one insert so that makes me believe that my operations don't happen one after another but maybe in parallel? 
How should I handle:

- multiple operations in one transaction
- handle `then()` when rows is empty so just skip to the next `then()`

Comment: Your `process` function never resolves. You don't need to create `new Promise` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In agreement with @Mikael , you don't need the `new Promise`, but also I think you need to `return knex.transaction(`, so that that the transaction function is completed before additional processing is done?

```
function process(params){
  return knex.transaction(function(trx){
        return insertRows(rows, trx)
    }).then(function (result){
        return insertRows(rows2,trx)
    }).then(function (result){
      return updateRows(rows3,trx)
    });
}
```

Since you didn't `return knex.transaction()`, this operation will be 'disconnected' from the caller's sequence, running asynchronously.

Your `return Promise.resolve() //this is probably wrong` is fine. You are returning a resolved promise in the `else`, just like in the `if` portion of the function. Because that (sub)function is only called within a `Promise` ... `.then`, you could actually omit the `else` clause, because the `.then` statement automatically converts synchronous function return values into resolved promises.

Comment: how variable trx can be used in `insertRows(rows2,trx)`. I am getting  trx is not defined.